# not reload when click submit button

Tags: php

here is my code:

member.php (page)

```
<?php

$membertype=$_POST['txtmtn'];
$bookalit=$_POST['txtbal'];
$issueprd=$_POST['txtisp'];
$finegp=$_POST['selectfinegp'];
include '../connection.php';


if(isset($_POST['bttnsave']))
{
$sql="UPDATE member_type SET BookAllotmentLimit='$bookalit', IssueForPeriod='$issueprd',
FineGroupName='$finegp' WHERE MemberTypeName='$membertype'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
}
?>

<form method="post" action="media.php">
<input type="text" name="txtmtn" id="txt" >
<input type="submit" name="bttncfg" id="button2" value="Create Fine Group" onClick="window.open('fine group.php', 'win1','width=420,height=320')">
```

when i click 'bttncfg' button a fine group.php will be open but member.php's txtmtn value will lost..

Comment: By the way what are you trying to do? and what a pop up will do ?

Comment: i m trying to save data into the database but not reloading page it mean that the text field data will show & also save in database

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="submit" name="bttncfg" id="button2" value="Create Fine Group" onClick="window.open('fine group.php', 'win1','width=420,height=320'); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

At `<input type="submit"....` you need action, where you post the value. It will be the page name where you want to post the value and in that page you will get value by `$_POST[' ']`

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action and give it target:

```html
<form method="post" action="fine group.php" target="win1">
```

This way the form will get posted to the correct page inside new browser window.

Comment: Cheers, feel free to Accept the answer (click the V icon to the left) in such case. :)